# W/ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord (closing the interstitial)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

Hello I get the following warning when closing the interstitial ad between activity and activity 2 (android studio Logcat):

```
2022-06-10 14:30:09.946 845-861/? W/ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{28d281bb u0 com.example.testads/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity t13 f}
```

I am using:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.0.0

Does anyone else get this warning in logcat?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have detected the problem! It called twice in different parts of the code: mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() { ...... }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).